# The sum of the reciprocals of the Carmichael-numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, carmichael-numbers

Let $C_n$ be the $n$-th Carmichael-number and $$r:=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{C_j}$$

If we stop at the last Carmichael-number below $10^{16}$ ,we get $$0.0047065376661376\cdots $$ as an approximation.

> How accurate will this approximation of $r$ be ? I assume this sum will converge although I have not rigorously proven it yet.

The bounds given in Wikipedia or Mathworld for the number of Carmichael-numbers below some given number $n$ are not very suitable for an estimate (not very tight and not even very concrete). What else can I do ?

Comment: as i recall, Pomerance made some conjectures regarding the distribution of Carmichael numbers, but I don't know if they help here and, more importantly, I think deep searches have cast doubt on them.  [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=00080990e57b908e9e6ff708cb74bf03015fef7d) is a paper that describes some of this, but I have not checked it for accuracy (nor for direct relevance to this question).  Personally, I'm kind of surprised the sum is this small.

Comment: For those who don't know Carmichael numbers : https://oeis.org/A002997

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem:** The sum $r$ of the reciprocals of the Carmichael numbers satisfies
$$
0.004706<r<27.8724.
$$
For a proof see [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL20/Bayless/bayless3.pdf). It seems that your value is rather accurate, but I haven't seen a proof.

Comment: I didn't know that it had already been shown that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers. Age put us out of place......